# Camera Raw Update doesnt work photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So in help/updates... I have Photoshop Camera Raw 7. I need at least vesion 9.6 for my camera.

I tried to update it but it just doesnt.

I'm using windows 7. My photoshop is in french.

Ive downloaded the update from the website, from the photoshop.

Thx for help

Comment: "I tried to update it but it just doesnt." = It runs, no errors, but no change in configuration?

Comment: When I look at the preferences it's still in Photoshop Camera Raw 7. I still cant open CR2 files. I run the update everyting look fine but nothing changed.

Comment: You don't mention Photoshop Version.

Comment: CS6 in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera Raw 9.6 is not available for CS6, you must use their DNG converter to convert the RAW files to DNG.

> Update to camera support policy in CS6
>
> In order to pursue further innovations in image processing and
>   workflow technology, the next release of Adobe Camera Raw (v 9.1.1)
>   will be the final version available for use with CS6.   Customers can
>   utilize the free Adobe DNG Converter utility to receive the very
>   latest camera support for CS6 and older versions of our software going
>   all the way back to Photoshop CS1 and Lightroom 1.0.
>
> DNG Converter
>
> Download and Install DNG Converter:
>
> ```
> Mac: http://www.adobe.com/go/dng_converter_mac
> Win: http://www.adobe.com/go/dng_converter_win
> ```

http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2015/07/update-to-camera-support-policy-in-cs6.html

Comment: So I need the CC version ?

Comment: No. Just use the converter to convert the camera RAW files to DNG and then you can open them using the Camera Raw v.7 plugin. Apparently the converter understands the formats (it is probably built into the plugin in some manner), they just don't want to continue supporting the Photoshop CS6 user interface.

Comment: Do I lose some image quality during that conversion?

Comment: This is going to vary a little I expect, but DNG is a RAW format created by Adobe. It is plausible that some of the data is transformed (RAW is rarely or never RGB 8-bit, but varies based on sensor configuration [2-channels; 14 bit, 12-bit]) in a way that loses precision. It may also alter or strip the camera profile meta-data, which isn't a loss per-se, but you may need to come up with a custom preset transformation when opening them. I think it may also store the the original RAW data unconverted inside